# Javascript disable select box on another select box option

Tags: javascript, html

I have two select dropdown lists:

```
<select name="internal_message">
<option value="yes">Yes</option>
<option value="" selected="selected">No</option>
</select>
```

and

```
<select name="internal_message_agent">
<option value="">Choose</option>.... etc
</select>
```

I have tried:

```
<select name="internal_message">
            <option value="yes" onClick="document.getElementById('internal_message_agent').disabled=!this.selected;">Yes</option>
            <option value="" selected="selected">No</option>
            </select>
```

but it doesnt work - how can i get it working to disable the internal_message_agent select element to be disabled when the internal_message selected value is `"No"` and enable it when the selected option is `"Yes"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an ID to each select and use jquery to disable it like so:

```
$('#box1').on('change', function(){
if($(this).val()==='no'){
    $('#box2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}else{
    $('#box2').attr('disabled', false);
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3MCaG/1/

Comment: Good answer. I would just also add the disabled attribute to the `internal_message_agent` and add an extra blank `<option></option>` to the list to prevent any default selections. +1!

Comment: how about if the internal_message option "No" is selected the internal_message_agent will be disabled and if the selected option is "Yes" the internal_message_agent will be enabled

Comment: I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: if internal_message = 'Yes' then internal_message_agent = enabled else if internal_message = 'No' then internal_message_agent = disabled

Comment: its not working like that - its not disabling at all?

Comment: on your site or jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't duplicate your problem it seems to work across all of my devices / browsers

Comment: Have you tried the latest fiddle? i did edit the answer from my first response http://jsfiddle.net/3MCaG/1/

Comment: Aha - i see. it wasnt disabled on page load - have sorted it now thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's what it would look like with Javascript and HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script>
function validate(){
    var b1 = document.getElementById("box1");
    var f = b1.options[b1.selectedIndex].value;
    var b2 = document.getElementById("box2");
        if(f == "no"){
        b2.disabled="disabled";
        }
    else{
    b2.disabled="";
    }
}
</script>
<select id="box1" onchange="validate()">
    <option id="yes" value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option id="no" value="no" selected="selected">No</option>
</select>

<select id="box2" disabled>
    <option></option>
    <option value="">Choose</option>
</select>
</html>
```